# How does wso2 deploy on Kubernetes without using Google Cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to deploy WSO2 API Manager with Kubernetes.
Should I use Google Cloud?
Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helm charts [1](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim) for APIM can be deployed on GKE, AKS, EKS, etc. You can even deploy the all-in-one simple deployment pattern [2](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/tree/master/simple/am-single) in a local Kubernetes cluster like minikube, etc.

You might have to use a cloud provider for more advanced patterns since they require more resources to run.

All these charts are there as samples to get an idea about the deployment patterns. It is not recommended to deploy those as it is in real production scenarios as the resource requirements and infrastructure vary according to the use cases.

[1](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim) - https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim

[2](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/tree/master/simple/am-single) - https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/tree/master/simple/am-single